# PHP: Removing elements from array

Tags: php, arrays

My question is about the PHP functions for manipulating array elements, like array_pop() and array_shift().

On all examples I've seen (including php.net), since those functions return the value being removed, they are assigned to a variable when executed, for example:

```
$exampleArray=array("1","2","3");
$removedNum=array_pop($exampleArray);
```

What I can't find is whether you have to assign the removed value or could you just pop the value from the end and be done with it, like in Ruby, for example. 
I have tried and it works, e.g.:

```
array_pop($exampleArray);
```

but I'm not sure if this is an acceptable practice in PHP programming? Or should I always assign the value to a variable?

Comment: Thanks Paul, just wanted to make sure it wouldn't cause some issue in a large-scale application.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid to use `array_pop()` and `array_shift()` to remove unwanted values, and in some cases, can even make sense depending on the data that you're working with.

I.e., if you are working with CSV files, and have an array of lines from that file, where the first line is header data that you know will never change (a bold assumption), and that does not matter to your script, you can safely remove that first line from your array before starting the loop to process the values.

As for whether that's a good practice or not, that's something to discuss with the people maintaining your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

```
array_pop($exampleArray);
```

You don't have to assign the value to a variable if you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your application is doing. For example if your application really needs to save the last number being popped then yes. Otherwise, you don't need the variable. Furthermore, It takes memory to create a variable. It may not seem as much for small operations but if you have a loop of a billion operations, then this becomes wasteful. As long as you code is readable, you'll be fine :).